# How to create a static array from objects in controller (ASP.NET MVC) without overwriting every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, static

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. In the `HomeController`, I want to create an array of objects of the class I need, so that when new objects are written to this array, it would not be overwritten, but added as new elements to itself.

For example: this is a piece of code from `HomeController`. Here I create a static array of objects so that we can access it without creating a class object.

```
// ...

public static List<Person> personMessages { get; set; }

public HomeController()
{
    personMessages = new List<Person>();
}

// ...
```

And this is the code from another class, in which I add new objects to this array (`personMessages`).

```
HomeController.personMessages.Add(personObj);
Console.WriteLine("Array count: " + HomeController.personMessages.Count);
```

When my application is running, after each addition of a new object, the length of the array will always be `1` and it will contain the last added object.

How to solve my problem and create something like a data repository (based on my array of objects `personMessages`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really bad to have `personMessages`  as a member of the controller class. and you are accessing it using the controller class. It violates the single responsibility principle as well.

you should create a repository class and have a static member of it. you can create a method to add an item to the list.

```
public static class PersonRepository
{
    public static List<Person> personMessages { get; set; } = new List<Person>();

    public static void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        personMessages.Add(person);
    }
}
```

you can call the method like this `PersonRepository.AddPerson(personObj)`;

As a suggestion, I think you should use some logging instead of `Console.WriteLine` as it's not a console application.